# 403 error while posting to Sharepoint REST social API

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am having a problem with Sharepoint Rest social API.
Here's the code to like a post I got from googling around

```
function likePost() {
    var postId = '1.0f435d74164149cfa76e19ad21dc7c2e.8a7874906a9348189f2fb83295b598d5.06ff4087162c48dcb43828e4ddf82c38.98b9fc73d5224265b039586688b15b98.8ec3fc561f084e6b98bfb117e9c23022.64.64.1';
    $.ajax( {
        url: "/_api/social.feed/Post/Like",
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        }, 
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'ID': postId
        }),
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Success");
            var jsonObject = data.d.ID;
            alert(jsonObject);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
            alert("POST error:\n" + xhr.status + "\n" + thrownError);
        }
    });
}
```

However when I try this on my Sharepoint site, I always get 403 FORBIDDEN error.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you're not authenticated to SharePoint. You'll need an auth token to talk to most of SharePoint's REST services.

Comment: I am logging into the system with an admin account which has full control right

Comment: Yes, but where is this code running in relation to your SharePoint site? If you're not writing code that runs from within the app web (i.e. a SharePoint app or web part), you are required to use an OAuth access token. It's not going to pass authentication automatically otherwise.

Comment: Yes I did put the code inside a WebPart.

Comment: Even in a web part, this is client code running in the context of a user's web browser. It's not running in the security context of the web part.

Comment: Then how can I make it run in the security context of the webpart?

Comment: Use SharePoint's server object model.

Answer (score -1):

In your application, you need to go into the AppManifest, go to the permissions, and give it permission to the "User Profiles (Social)" with at least Read permission.

This will allow your application to have access to the elements that it looks like you're trying to hit.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163864.aspx